# framer-motion, is there a way to start animation after component's render,css..etc.. all completed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, framer-motion

I getting a problem with framer-motion

the problem is,

- CSS border-radius working after animated, but I want animation with rounded-border
- some text data is showing up after animated, (I guess.. React is updating the state on 'AnimationEnd' event trigger)

Is there a way to start animation after all these things are done?

Comment: Can you show a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Framer motion's `useAnimation` hook provides an way to tell framer when to start the animation.

You can use a useEffect hook, and call the start animation function inside the hook, depending on when you want to start.

Refer this => https://www.framer.com/docs/animation/#component-animation-controls

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).